# How to map an owned property to a private field

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I have a value object, which means that its properties have getters but not setters. Then I have an entity with a public getter and a private field. Something like the following:

```
public class Settings {
  private string _instance;
  private string _domain;

  public Settings(string instance, string domain) {
    _instance = instance;
    _domain = domain;
  }
  private Settings() {
    _instance = default!;
    _domain = default!;
  }

  public string Instance => _instance;
  public string Domain => _domain;
}

public class Tenant {
  private Guid _id;
  private string _name;
  private Settings _settings;

  public Tenant(string name) {
    _id = Guid.Empty;
    _name = name;
    _settings = new Settings("etc", "etc");
  }
  private Tenant() {
    _id = default;
    _name = default!;
    _settings = default!;
  }

  public Guid Id => _id;
  public string Name => _name;
  public Settings => _settings;

  protected void OnSettingsChanged() { 
    // do stuff like adding domain events and sending notifications 
  }
  public void ChangeSetting(Settings newSettings) {
    // do some model validation
    _settings = newSettings;
    OnSettingsChanged();
  }
}
```

I'm using C# 8, .NET Core 3 and Entity Frmework Core 3. Now in my implementation of `IEntityTypeConfiguration<Tenant>`, for configuring say Name I have no problem, as I can use HasField and pass the name of the private property. But that is not working for Settings. There, I use OwnsOne, but there is no HasField property available.

```
builder.Property(x => x.Name)
  .HasField("_name")
  .HasMaxLength(100);
builder.OwnsOne(x.Settings, y => {
  y.Property(z => z.Instance)
   .HasField("_instance")
   .IsRequired(true);
  y.Property(z => z.Domain)
   .HasField("_domain")
   .IsRequired(true);
  //y.HasField() ??
});
```

However I can't find a way to tell EF that the Settings property should be mapped to the private `_settings` variable. I tried adding a call to `Property` before the call to `OwnsOne`:

```
...
builder.Property(x => x.Settings)
  .HasField("_settings");
builder.OwnsOne(x.Settings, y => {
  y.Property(z => z.Instance)
   .HasField("_instance")
   .IsRequired(true);
  y.Property(z => z.Domain)
   .HasField("_domain")
   .IsRequired(true);
});
```

But then when I add a migration, I get an error: The property or navigation 'Settings' cannot be added to the entity type 'Tenant' because a property or navigation with the same name already exists on entity type 'Tenant', which I suppose happens because I'm configuring the property Settings twice.

So how could I achieve this, what's the equivalent of HasField when using OwnsOne? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all these `HasField` calls because in EF Core 3.0 [Backing fields are used by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#backing-fields-are-used-by-default) and also your backing fields follow one of the EF Core [property backing field naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field#conventions), so EF Core will automatically discover and use them (you still need `Property` calls though because get only properties are not discovered by convention).

But let say you need to specify the backing field of the property in question. `Property` method cannot be used because by EF Core terminology these are not properties, but *navigations*. There is no fluent API similar to `HasField` for property builders, so you have to use directly the mutable metadata services:

```
builder.OwnsOne(x => x.Settings, y =>
{
    // ...
    y.Metadata.PrincipalToDependent.SetField("_settings");
});
```

It's similar to relationship navigation properties. The `Metadata` property of the corresponding builder returns `IMutableForegnKey` object. `PrincipalToDependent` and `DependentToPrincipal` properties return `IMutableNavigation` objects which can be used to configure the corresponding navigation property.

Comment: I see, thank you. Would it harm if I use the Metadata.PrincipalToDependant.SetField call, if only to make it explicitly clear (say, for other members of the team)? As an example, our team has a convention to explicitly call IsRequired(true) or IsRequired(false), to make it abundantly clear...

Comment: It would be redundant, but won't hurt :)